# Hive dataype for date

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

```
Date;Time;Global_active_power;Global_reactive_power;Voltage;Global_intensity;Sub_metering_1;Sub_metering_2;Sub_metering_3
16/12/2008;17:24:00;4.216;0.418;234.840;18.400;0.000;1.000;17.000
16/12/2008;17:25:00;5.360;0.436;233.630;23.000;0.000;1.000;16.000
16/12/2008;17:26:00;5.374;0.498;233.290;23.000;0.000;2.000;17.000
16/12/2008;17:27:00;5.388;0.502;233.740;23.000;0.000;1.000;17.000
16/12/2008;17:28:00;3.666;0.528;235.680;15.800;0.000;1.000;17.000
16/12/2008;17:29:00;3.520;0.522;235.020;15.000;0.000;2.000;17.000
16/12/2008;17:30:00;3.702;0.520;235.090;15.800;0.000;1.000;17.000
16/12/2008;17:31:00;3.700;0.520;235.220;15.800;0.000;1.000;17.000
16/12/2008;17:32:00;3.668;0.510;233.990;15.800;0.000;1.000;17.000
```

This is the sample data, i am really confused with the datatype to be used for Date and Time.
  plese help,

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to be looking at the TimeStamp datatype which has this format:yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
There is also a Date datatype which takes this format: YYYY-­mm-­dd
There isn't a seperate time datatype. If you can't change the sample data you probably want to load the dates as string and use udfs like unix_timestamp(string date, string pattern) then copy to result into a new table.